# OS X game engine

Tags: macos, game-engine

can someone recommend game engine for creating quest game like "tiny bang story" or "machinarium" for OS X?
I've read about cocos2d, unity, udk and it seems that using cocos2d is easer for development.

Or maybe there is no need to use engine and it will be enough to use OpenGL with core image and core animation?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk The MacOS version is in beta. But the engine is intended mainly for adventure games.